# Time server connect calculate

Tags: javascript

```
var serverTime1 = $('#commands_outgoings > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3) > span').html().split(':');
 var serverTime = $('#serverTime').html().split(':');
console.log(serverTime1)

console.log(serverTime)
0: "14"
1: "05"
2: "11"


console.log(serverTime1)
0: "21"
1: "01"
2: "10"
```

how to change 3 array at a time (when I refresh the page) 0 1 2 (0 hours)(1minute) (2second)

or

```
var actualtime = $("#serverTime")[0].innerText;
var endtime = $("#commands_outgoings > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3) > span")[0].innerText;
```

format

15:06:45
and
19:59:35
how create refresh time? (tampermonkey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var time1 = $("#content_value > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(11) > tbody > tr:nth-child(10) > td:nth-child(2) > span")[0].innerText;
var timeParts1 = time1.split(":");
var cas = (((+timeParts1[0] * (60000 * 60)) + (+timeParts1[1] * 60000) + (+timeParts1[2] * 1000)));
```

solved